# When trying to access a different class it refers to a the actual form?

Tags: c#

As you can see from below, i have 2 class: MovieProperty and Form1. But whenever i try to access Form1 from MovieProperty i seem to get the design of Form1 but i want to access the code to use the variable "MovieList". By the way, I'm new to this kind of lang and i would want a explanation to the solution, so in the future, i'd hopefully avoid this issue

```
public partial class MovieProperty : Form
{
    public MovieProperty()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ConfirmMovie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = MovieNameTxt.Text;

    }
    private void details(string movie)
    {
        Form1 formzz = new Form1();
        formzz.movielist
    }
}
```

In the other class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static List<string> movielist = new List<string>();

    private void AddMovie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MovieProperty mv = new MovieProperty();
        mv.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are enough problems with this code that I'm not sure we'll be able to help much.  Start with a good tutorial.  In particular, you could use help with access modifiers and the concept of classes vs. objects (i.e. what `new Form1()` actually does)

Comment: For what it's worth, I like the name "Lemon Flamingo".

Answer (score 1):

Class members are private by default. Declare the movie list as public to be able to access it from another class.

Also, you declared the list as static. This means that it exists once, independently of how many `Form1` objects you are creating. Static members are accessed through the class name (`Form1.movielist`). Remove `static` to make it an instance member.

```
public List<string> movielist = new List<string>();
```

But it is better to provide external access through a property

```
private List<string> _movielist = new List<string>();
public  List<string> MovieList
{
    get { return _movielist; }
}
```

This encapsulates the list.

See

1. [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx) (Jon Skeet, C# in Depth)
2. [Encapsulation (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) (Wikipedia)
3. [Static and instance members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx) (msdn)
4. [Declared accessibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691127(v=vs.71).aspx) (msdn)

Comment: This answer seems the most suitable one.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable Form1.movielist is private by default and therefore not available from MovieProperty.  You can mark it public if you want it available to MovieProperty.  Also since you've marked it static, you would call it like this:

```
Form1.movielist;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made your list as static so it is independent of the instance. To access the list use the class name and not the instance name.

```
Form1.movielist
```

If you had not made it static, you would get a new list with each instance and would need to use the instance name to refer to it.